# ¿Cómo cambio las iniciales de los días a español en el CalendarView?

Tags: java, android-studio, xml

[image: Captura de Android Studio]

Lo que quiero es que las letras de los días sean en español Do-Lu-Ma-Mi-Ju-Vi-Sa y no en ingles como se ve en la imagen S-M-T-W-T-F-S no se si se podría hacer directamente del XML o a través de código.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

0

Las letras de los días de la semana de CalendarView, por defecto, te muestran el idioma en que tengas configurado el tlfno en que estás ejecutando la ap o bien el de donde estés realizando las pruebas de la aplicación (emulador) , si los pones en español te aparecerán las letras de los días de la semana en español.

Me explico..

en Android Studio o en el emulador, si están en inglés, se mostrarán así 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Mientras en el tlfno, si está en español, se mostrará así
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Esto podía ir como añadido a tu otra respuesta :)

Comment: Gracias! Si no me decías eso no me daba cuenta de que el teléfono estaba en idioma ingles.

Answer (score 0):

Prueba con esto, creo que esta es una posible solución a tu problema

Instalación, en su archivo    /app/build.gradle

```
repositories {
  maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
}

dependencies {
   compile 'com.github.MorochoRochaDarwin:OneCalendarView:3.1.1'
}
```

Luego agregar la vista OneCalendarView al Layout Y ponemos el idioma en español

```
  <com.darwindeveloper.onecalendar.views.OneCalendarView
    android:id="@+id/oneCalendar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:calendarLanguage="ES"
    />
```

Aquí tienes información más detallada

```
https://androidexample365.com/calendarview-personalizado-para-desarrolladores-android/
```

Comment: Para personalizar el CalendarView necesariamente tengo que instalar el OneCalendarView, lo que me refiero es hacerlo al CalendarView

Comment: Para personalizar CalendarView no tienes por qué instalar OneCalendarView, pero te simplifica las cosas.